# Sharing a function in a folder in C++

Tags: c++, function, include

Sorry for this question, which is probably a pretty nooby question, but i just don't know how to get my problem solved.

I have a function that returns true or false, rather the one number is a divider of an other number or not.

[image]

Now i need this function in two of my programs and instead of just copy-pasting it, i want to write this function in its own file and then include it in the programs.

What is the best way to do that?
I don't use VisualStudio, so I think I can't create a library.

Comment: Put the function in a header file and include the file.

Comment: _"I don't use VisualStudio, so I think I can't create a library."_ Not true. That's exactly what you should do.

Comment: A library may not be needed though. For that trivial function just putting it in a header should be enough.

Comment: Don't post code as images here please! You can format code her by indenting with four spaces.

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 3):

You can create a header-only "library". That is, a single header file, say "my.h", which contains the definition of your function:

```
#ifndef MY_LIBRARY_UNIQUE_ID_OR_SOMETHING //these are called include guards, 
#define MY_LIBRARY_UNIQUE_ID_OR_SOMETHING //look them up

inline bool myFunc()
{
    return true;
}

#endif
```

Do note that the function **must** be inline. Otherwise you may get "function redefinition" linker errors.

In order to use this "library", all you have to do is #include "my.h" (with correct path, of course). Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Create a file with an extension `.h`. For example: `myheader.h`

Then write to `myheader.h` the following:

```
#ifndef MYHEADER_H
#define MYHEADER_H

bool is_divider(int, int);

#endif
```

Write a `source` file named `myheader.cpp`

Inside the `myheader.cpp` write:

```
#include"myheader.h"

bool is_divider(int a, int b) {
    /your code here
}
```

`include` the header `myheader.h` to the files you need to use `is_divider()`

Note that if you are using an IDE you should do the following:

1. Add the `.cpp` and `.h` files to your project
2. Include the path of the headers on the IDE options.

For example, if you are using codeblocks you can see the process [here](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=FAQ#Q:_I_would_like_to_compile_a_project_using_some_non-standard_libraries._How_can_I_indicate_to_CodeBlocks_that_these_libraries_and_include_files_exist.3F) (keep in mind that same procedure applies in other IDE's as well)

If you are using a terminal and an editor you can create a `makefile`. A nice tutorial can be found [here](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/ug/larger/makefiles.html)

Comment: It won't be enough to #include "myheader.h". You will have to link against myHeader.obj as well...

Comment: You also need to add the cpp file to each project you want to use this.

Comment: The cpp file also need to be included in the project otherwise it will not be compiled and there will be link errors.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan Indeed but I do not know if he uses an IDE or an editor and a terminal

Comment: @NathanOliver I agree but I don't know if he uses an IDE. Give me a sec I will edit the answer

Comment: It's said in the OP that VS is not used.

Comment: edit was done :) thank you all for the comments/feedback!!

Comment: It is still not right.  The C++ file need to be included into the project if using an IDE or call out explicitly is compiling via a command line.

Comment: @NathanOliver I really do appreciate your feedback, even though the link covers this topic its nice to be precise by writing complete answers. Thank you.

Comment: No problem.  Thanks for fixing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a header file to share the function between both programs.  The header file extension can take different forms.  The most common extension is .h however there are others such as .hpp.

**For example, a header file named foo.h might contain:**

```
#pragma once  // include this file just once

inline bool foo()
{
   return false;
}
```

**To use the header file you would include it from the .cpp file as follows:**

```
#include "foo.h"  // when foo.h is located in the same directory as the .cpp file
#include <foo.h>  // when foo.h is located in a project additional include folder
#include "../foo.h"  //when foo.h is located up one directory from the .cpp file
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a header file with the function. Here are 3 options:

---

### Option 1

***Define function in header file***

Here is an example:

Create a file `header.h`
Give it the following code:

```
#pragma once
inline int random()
{
    return 4; //Strictly random
}
```

If your compiler doesn't support `#pragma`, use header guards, like this:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_OR_ID
#define HEADER_ H_OR_ID
inline int random()
{
    return 4; //Strictly random
}
#endif
```

For this option, every file that wants to use the function has to include `"header.h"`

---

### Option 2

***Forward declare the function in a header file, and implement in every source file***

Example:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_OR_ID
#define HEADER_H_OR_ID
int random();
#endif
```

`Source.cpp`

```
#include "header.h"
int random() {return 4;}
```

But unfortunately, this is not probably not what you want, although it allows uniqueness per file.

---

### Option 3

***Forward declare the function in a header file, and implement in corresponding source file***

Example:
`Header.h`

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
int random();
#endif
```

`Header.cpp`

```
#include "Header.h"
int random() {return 4;}
```

Here, you have to include the source file with the main file, such as by linking them on the command line like this:

```
g++ main.cpp header.cpp
```

Tools like Visual Studio already would link all files, so nothing manual, other than creating files, is necessary.

Comment: In option 1 why forward declare?  Why would you ever do option 2?

Comment: Option 2 was just an alternative, as I mentioned at the end of the answer, Option 1 was a copy/paste typo. Will fix that. @NathanOliver Answer is updated

Comment: But you would never have the declaration in the header file and the implementation in *every source file* ... Just have one source file that you link ...

Comment: That is one way of doing it, but I didn't write it, since @KostasRim already wrote that in his answer